# black screen, start up GUI without rebooting?

Tags: freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Intel NUC machine.

My computer just turned black when I started Firefox. The screen however is still responsive when I move the mouse and enter keys on my keyboard while in console mode (ctrl+alt+F1). This has happened to me a few times (not because of Firefox each time though). I can easily fix it by restarting the computer, but I was working on some unsaved lenghty documents (Gedit).

Is there a way to save my work via console mode or get the GUI back up again without restarting?

Edit:

- I can't access the desktop/GUI, I only have the console via ctrl+alt+F1. I wrote startx through the console and I got a lot of text/information, now what? I read the startx info page you provided and I can't see any useful information or relevant guidance there.
- Yes, I have another computer. What of it?
- I've tried PS but I get pages of posts and I can't scroll up to find specifically the Firefox process ID. How do I narrow it down? A bit help with the right commands to enter would be greatly appreciated as well!

Comment: Do you have another computer you can connect from?

Comment: From the console, run ps and id the process running firefox, kill it, freeing up some memory, and save your work.

Comment: I've updated my original post with answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window, type `startx` to restart your GUI. More detail in [man startx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/startx.1.html).

Comment: Since I specifically mentioned that I can't access the desktop/GUI I can only write that through the console which I access via ctrl+alt+F1, I assume that you're on board with that fact. 

So. I wrote startx through the console and I got a lot of text/information, now what? I read the link you provided and I can't see any useful information or relevant guidance there.

Comment: _I got a lot of text/information_ Then, please click [edit] and add that information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]